# How to use a style attribute within a {% static %} tag?

Tags: html, django

This is `html` line which throws an error in `VScode`:

```
style="{% static 'background-image:url(images/home_slider.jpg)' %}"
```

1. } expected
2. at-rule or selector expected
3. Do not use empty rulesets
   how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The [**`{% static … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#static) will only translate the parameter to a URI. It does not know in what "context" it is working. If you want to pass a static image in the `url(..)` of style fragment, you can do this with:

```
style="background-image:url({% static 'images/home_slider.jpg' %})"
```